# Ridiculous error trace in tsc. How to add more verbose?

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, compilation

I´m trying to compile a react project with the default `tsconfig.json` provided by `create-react-app` and I´m getting this absurd error that I cannot find the source.

```
$ tsc
error TS2488: Type 'never' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

when I try to run `npm run build` I get:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

TypeScript error in undefined(undefined,undefined):
Type 'never' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.  TS2488
```

YES! That is all I get, nothing else. No file, no nothing. Is there a way to get more verbose, or find a complete log of the compiler? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try npm run build -- --verbose

Check:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config